# How to join a logic table on multiple columns/parmeters that also contain NULL to the actual data table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a data table like this

**Devices**

| Device | Status | Status_Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mouse | Old | Broken bluetooth function |
| Keyboard | New | Cmd key sticky |
| Monitor | Really Old | Null |

And then I have a logic table constructed like this

**Logic**

| Device | Age | Status_Comment | Replace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| % | Really old | 'NULL' | Yes |
| % | Really old | ANY | Yes |
| Mouse | New | %broken% | Yes |
| Keyboard | Old | %sticky% | Yes |
| Keyboard | New | %sticky% | No, replace switch |

I want to be able to join the logic table so that I can use the logic in it to derive the Replace field to the existing data, which would expect to look like:

| Device | Age | Status_Comment | Replace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mouse | Old | broken bluetooth function | Yes |
| Keyboard | New | Cmd key sticky | No, replace switch |
| Monitor | Really Old | Null | Yes |

How would I achieve this?

I currently have such tables, but when I join them on all relevant columns like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Devices d
LEFT JOIN Logic l ON d.Device = l.Device
                  AND d.Age = l.Age
                  AND d.Status_Comment = l.Status_Comment
```

All of the values in the joined fields from the logic table show as NULL. However if I join on just one of the columns, values show; however, this means not all of the logic is being applied. Is the issue that the logic table has "NULL" values, which cannot be joined?

How would I be able to still apply the logic of the table if this is the case?

Edit: replaced previous example with one more similar to my issue where all fields are of type nvarchar(50), not null.

I have also tried joining on LIKE instead of = but same issue with all Nulls.

Comment: Add the table definitions to your question. How does `'4' equate to 'ANY'`...?

Comment: `NULL`s are one of the problems, yes. `NULL = <any value, even another NULL>` evaluates to `NULL` which isn't true (but not false, SQL's ternary logic applies here). ...

Comment: ... But also the other values (mostly) don't add up. For example in `logic.age` you have the *string* `'ANY'`, that's never equal to `4`, neither is `'>= 5'` equal to `4`. `'Broken bluetooth function'` is never equal to `'%broken%'`. Etc.. There won't be any magic happening and the DBMS will start to try to interpret your strings that just *describe* the logic all by itself. You yourself need to build something around it, so that the logic recorded in the table is correctly applied.

Comment: @Stu hmmm this may be the source of my issue/confusion. All fields in my actual tables (both the logic and the data itself) are nvarchar(50), not null, so the Null outputs are a result of empty string values. The difference between using % vs ANY parameters in the logic table is supposed to account for when that field is blank or not. Will try edit the Q to better reflect this.

Comment: @marcusory: "Would joining on LIKE solve this?" -- Not in general, no, only where `LIKE` is the right operator. "Is there a workaround for this?" -- What do you mean by work around in this context? Get around the work *you* have to do? As I wrote there is no magic here. You need to somehow build a kind of an interpreter that translates the logic's description and the given values into an actual Boolean operation the DBMS can work with.

Comment: @stickybit gotchya! Makes sense. Would joining on LIKE solve this? I previously had tried this but was unsuccessful - perhaps I was doing it incorrectly. The logic table I have cannot be edited and I am required to use it as-is to evaluate the existing dataset.

Comment: @marcusory: See my previous comment, that already answered you previous (now deleted) comment. It answers your new one as well.

Comment: @stickybit Okay, I see. Well the scope of what I was assigned for this did not encompass re-creating anything and is beyond my role. Was mainly curious if such functionality is built into t-sql for working with logic tables specifically, or if the join condition could somehow be revised to do so (it's not typically a part of my role), but you provided the answer to that. Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for some kind of `eval` functionality, which does not really exists, at least not on the level of a single query. You can perhaps setup a table which provides a few basic expressions, you would need some big `CASE` expressions to be able to process it though